# How do I fetch single documents from a Database?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

So I've got this page which puts out all of the profiles on my database and what I want to do is when someone clicks on an individual profile they go in to a profile page which displays the rest of the data for the corresponding id they have just clicked on but I don't seem to be able to get it to work.
Below is my js file to get individual profiles.

```
import { projectFirestore } from "../Firebase/Config";
import { ref } from "vue"

const getPBasic = (id) => {
    const PBasic = ref(null)
    const error = ref(null)

    const load = async () => {
        try{
            let res = await projectFirestore.collection('Basic').doc(id).get()

            PBasic.value = {...res.data(), id: res.id}
               console.log(PBasic.value)
            
        }
        catch (err){
            error.value = err.message
            console.log(error.value)
        }
    }

    return { PBasic, error, load}
}

export default getPBasic
```

And this is what the vue page which I want the data to appear on after they have clicked on a profile from the previous page.

```
<script>
import getPBasic from "../Composables/getPBasic";
const {PBasic, error, load} = getPBasic(route.params.id);
load();

export default {
  name: "Slider",
  data() {
    return {
     images: [
        "/src/assets/sample-1.jpg",
        "/src/assets/sample-2.jpg",
       "/src/assets/sample-3.jpg",
        "/src/assets/sample-4.jpg"
      ],
      
      currentIndex: 0
    };
  },


  methods: {
 

    next: function() {
      this.currentIndex += 1;
    },
    prev: function() {
      this.currentIndex -= 1;
    }
  },

  computed: {
    currentImg: function() {
      return this.images[Math.abs(this.currentIndex) % this.images.length];
    }
  }
};

</script>
<template>
<div v-if="error">{{ error }}</div>
<div v-if="PBasic" class="PBasic">
<br><br>
<p>{{ PBasic.Name }} </p>
<p>{{ PBaic.Age }} </p>
</div>
 <div v-else>
  <spinner/>
 </div>
```

Thats what I've got so far I just shortened it for here so it didn't go on and on for too long, if anyone has any ideas I would greatly appreciate it, Thanks.

Comment: What error do you get? Also what is your Firebase version ?

Comment: version 9.9.3 This is the error I get in console runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:38 
        
       [Vue warn]: Property "PBasic" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance. 
  at <Slider onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< null > > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <App>

Answer (score 1):

You can run your `getPBasic` function in page load to fetch the data you need.

One possible solution is, Run your `getPBasic` function in a lifecycle hook that fire on page render like `mounted()` hook or `onMounted()` in vue3 script setup.

And as we can see your `getPBasic` function is a synchronous function so use `await` to get the return value properly.

One possible code might look like this,

```
<script>
import getPBasic from "../Composables/getPBasic";
const {PBasic, error, load} = getPBasic(route.params.id);

export default {
  name: "Slider",

  mounted(){
    let {PBasic,error,load} = await getPBasic();
    this.PBasic = PBasic;
    this.error = error;
    this.load = load;
  },

  data() {
    return {
     PBasic:{},
     error: null,
     load: false,
     images: [
        "/src/assets/sample-1.jpg",
        "/src/assets/sample-2.jpg",
       "/src/assets/sample-3.jpg",
        "/src/assets/sample-4.jpg"
      ],
      
      currentIndex: 0
    };
  },


  methods: {
 

    next: function() {
      this.currentIndex += 1;
    },
    prev: function() {
      this.currentIndex -= 1;
    }
  },

  computed: {
    currentImg: function() {
      return this.images[Math.abs(this.currentIndex) % this.images.length];
    }
  }
};

</script>
<template>
<div v-if="error">{{ error }}</div>
<div v-if="PBasic" class="PBasic">
<br><br>
<p>{{ PBasic.Name }} </p>
<p>{{ PBaic.Age }} </p>
</div>
 <div v-else>
  <spinner/>
 </div>
```